# Where is documentation of HP ProLiant Health Panel?

Tags: memory, hp, hp-proliant, health

This is a capture of one of our HP ProLiant ML370 G5 health panel (not sure about official name of the panel):

[image: Health Panel of a faulty HP ProLiant ML 370 G5.]

Why are all memory banks LED all on? Is it caused by a faulty memory bank?

Comment: They call it `Server System Insight Display (SID)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the service manual you want:

http://bizsupport2.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00710498/c00710498.pdf

LED info is on page 91.

According to that, those amber LEDs do indicate faulty FBDIMMS.